How to send events from google tag manager to google analytics ? I already did all the steps but i cannot see the events in debugview/realtime
Recently i am trying to track users journey through my website. I started by adding a tag in google tagmanger and trigger it with element visibilty.
I have tried adding a triger with elements visibilty using the css selector. The event is fired on google tagmanager bt i cannot see it on my google analytics debug view it showing only three events "Page_view" or "scroll".
